# "pygame.error: video system not initialized"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, mouseevent

Does anyone know why this error keeps coming up? I'm not sure what's wrong with the code. I've copied this from a video just to test mouse tracking and yet my version isn't working even though the two sets of code are identical (I believe). Here is the video I took the code from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxhNcQ-FDaY

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

class MousePos(object):
    def __init(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 24)  
        pygame.display.set_caption("Mouse Events")
        self.myScreen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400), 0 ,32)
        self.myScreen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pygame.display.update()

    def coords(self):
        text = self.myFont.render(str(pygame.mouse.get_pos()), True, (0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.myScreen, (255, 255, 255), (200, 200, 100, 100), 0)

        self.myScreen.blit(text, (200, 200))
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    newMouse = MousePos()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                newMouse.coords()
```

Comment: You got a typo, it's not `def __init` but `def __init__`

Comment: Please avoid just copying and pasting all your code into your question. Try to find the problematic line/lines of code, and post that. More than likely you'll see what the problem is yourself, before you post your question.

Comment: In all fairness the console was saying that the problem was on line 22 which wasn't the case

Comment: **Actual**, it was indeed the case. Python is telling you that it has a problem with you trying to use Pygame events. Unless it is a syntax error, Python is not going to tell you exactly where it had problem, rather, the indirect result of that problem. Python is not a debugger. If you want a debugger, use an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your initialization method `__init__`, is missing a underscore. Since your class is never being initialized, your never creating a Pygame screen. Thus the error

Change this line: `def __init(self):`, To this: `def __init__(self):`

Comment: I feel really thick now, thanks! I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be a missing dependency or library mismatch.
How did you install pygame, and were there any errors.
I recommend you use pip or your distribution's package manager.
Also, you should make sure that any non-python APIs and modules that you might need are all installed.

Comment: No, I the OP's code just has a typo. Pygame doesn't have any dependencies.